# How to remove characters from a string using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, string, lambda, char

I'm having a String like

`XQ74MNT8244A`

i nee to remove all the `char` from the string.

so the output will be like

`748244`

How to do this?
Please help me to do this

Comment: You don't need a `regex` - see @Tim Robinson's answer.

Comment: You don't want LINQ answers? Can you rewrite your question, or close it and post a new one?

Comment: Your question ask for LINQ, but your comment ask for regex. What do you actually want? In this case, I think LINQ is thebest solution as Tim Robinson's solution is by far more readable than any `RegEx`based solution.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
new string("XQ74MNT8244A".Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray()) == "748244"
```

Comment: +1. Very elegant. One question here. How does `Where(char.IsDigit)` work in this case? I would think that you have to write `Where(c => char.IsDigit(c))` here? Does the compiler do some magic in this case? An explanation would be appreciated here.

Comment: @Øyvind - no magic. `Char.IsDigit` is a function that takes a `char` and return a `bool` - exactly what `Where` expects. You don't have to wrap it in an anonymous function. (oh, and the compiler does a lot of magic anyway, like anonymous functions)

Comment: @Øyvind You can provide any delegate to the `Where` method; lambda syntax is only one way to obtain a delegate. If your lambda makes a direct call to some method, and the method's parameter types and return type match those of the lambda, you can provide the method name directly.

Comment: @Kobi and Tim - Thanks. I see that it should of course work this way, but I never thought about it. This might make my code a lot neater some places where I can omit the wrapper. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The value doesn't come in one string. It is indexed and separated. How to get the numbers or letters into one string?

Answer (score 12):

Two options. Using Linq on .Net 4 (on 3.5 it is similar - it doesn't have that many overloads of all methods):

```
string s1 = String.Concat(str.Where(Char.IsDigit));
```

Or, using a regular expression:

```
string s2 = Regex.Replace(str, @"\D+", "");
```

I should add that `IsDigit` and `\D` are Unicode-aware, so it accepts quite a few digits besides 0-9, for example `"542abc٣٤"`.
You can easily adapt them to a check between `0` and `9`, or to `[^0-9]+`.

Comment: A lot can be done using LINQ but that doesn't mean it should be used for everything. +1 for suggesting RegEx option.

Comment: The use of string.concat here is nicer than the .ToArray() I was thinking of using.

Comment: @Unmesh I agree it's easy to see Linq as a golden hammer, I've been guilty of that myself on some occasions.  In this case I think the Linq solution is much nicer to read than the Regex. (possibly much quicker as well)

Comment: @Andy - Thanks! Again, .Net 4 has an overload which accepts `IEnumerable<char>`, so it fits nicely, and probably optimized for that.

Answer (score 6):

```
string value = "HTQ7899HBVxzzxx";
Console.WriteLine(new string(
     value.Where(x => (x >= '0' && x <= '9'))
     .ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 2):

How about an extension method (and overload) that does this for you:

```
    public static string NumbersOnly(this string Instring)
    {
        return Instring.NumbersOnly("");
    }

    public static string NumbersOnly(this string Instring, string AlsoAllowed)
    {
        char[] aChar = Instring.ToCharArray();
        int intCount = 0;
        string strTemp = "";

        for (intCount = 0; intCount <= Instring.Length - 1; intCount++)
        {
            if (char.IsNumber(aChar[intCount]) || AlsoAllowed.IndexOf(aChar[intCount]) > -1)
            {
                strTemp = strTemp + aChar[intCount];
            }
        }

        return strTemp;
    }
```

The overload is so you can retain "-", "$" or "." as well, if you wish (instead of strictly numbers).

Usage:

```
string numsOnly = "XQ74MNT8244A".NumbersOnly();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need only digits and you really want Linq try this:

```
youstring.ToCharArray().Where(x => char.IsDigit(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: ToCharArray() is useless here as it implements IEnumerable

Comment: @PierrOz - That is absolutely true. However, Visual Studio 2008 Intellisense hides the `IEnumerable<Char>` extension methods, so it's easy to miss.

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ:

```
public string FilterString(string input)
{
    return new string(input.Where(char.IsNumber).ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
"XQ74MNT8244A".ToCharArray().Where(x => { var i = 0; return Int32.TryParse(x.ToString(), out i); })
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string s = "XQ74MNT8244A";
var x = new string(s.Where(c => (c >= '0' && c <= '9')).ToArray());
```