# Short and concise LINQ statement to remove all characters in a string that do match a criteria?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, string, linq-to-objects

How can do I something like:

```
string x;
string y = x.RemoveWhere(c => !char.IsLetter(c));
```

using LINQ?

Comment: Is there a reason `String.Replace` won't do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove characters from a string using LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366422/how-to-remove-characters-from-a-string-using-linq)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With LINQ:

```
string y = new string(x.Where(char.IsLetter).ToArray());
```

With Regex:

```
string y = Regex.Replace(x, "[^a-zA-Z]", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely string.Replace(c.ToString(), ""); would do it?

if you have to use LINQ for some reason (dunno why unless this is a homework question), something like

string y = new string(x.Where(c => char.IsLetter(c) ).ToArray());

Would do it, although theres a variety of ways.......